# Два деепричастных оборота: всё ли в порядке со знаками?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

> Он стоически переносил все трудности нашего приключения, **пребывая за
>   рулем по восемь – десять часов в день,** и, **выслушивая потоки
>   эмоциональной речи то на одном языке, то на другом,** сохранял полнейшую
>   невозмутимость.

Он переносил и сохранял, - остальное фиоритура?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно: Он переносил трудности  и сохранял невозмутимость.